# Cyclic convolution with CUDA

Tags: c++, math, cuda, fft, convolution

In the FFT2D paper

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_2/sdk/website/projects/convolutionFFT2D/doc/convolutionFFT2D.pdf

in the figure 1 and 2 it's stated that:

> assuming the image is bigger than the convolution kernel, which is 
>   usually the case in practice, the convolution kernel needs to be
>   expanded to the image  size and padded according to Figure 1. As can
>   be seen on figures 2 and 3 (see below),  cyclic convolution with the
>   expanded kernel is equivalent to cyclic convolution with  initial
>   convolution kernel.

If I perform the convolution between the kernel and the image for an element and I try to perform the convolution between the expanded kernel and the image for the same element, it yields different results.

I read somewhere that "cyclic convolution" is the same as a classic "convolution", is this correct? Otherwise how should I interpret this?

Comment: FFT always performs cyclic convolution.  If you don't want that, you need to pad both the image and the kernel, then crop the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a cyclic convolution, also known as a [circular convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution), is not the same as a regular convolution. The kernel "wraps around" in a circular convolution.

Take `x=[1 2 3 4 5]` and `h=[1 2 3]` for example:

First you flip `h` and pad with zeros: `h'=[0 0 3 2 1]`. Then to get the first element, you do the usual dot product:

```
(x*h)[0] = 0*1 + 0*2 + 3*3 + 2*4 + 1*5
```

To get the second element, you shift the kernel over by one and dot again:

```
(x*h)[1] = 0*1 + 1*2 + 2*3 + 3*4 + 0*5
```

Same with the third. To get the fourth though, the kernel wraps around so you get:

```
(x*h)[3] = 2*1 + 3*2 + 0*3 + 0*4 + 1*5
```

Comment: "regular" convolution isn't a standard term, in fact the word "regular" is a synonym for "periodic" or "cyclic".

Comment: And one point is cleared, thank you. Do you happen to know how a circular convolution between matrices is performed?